# PIXI shockwave filter

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Starting to play with PIXI and quickly realising the Documentation isn't so helpful. To me at least.

Trying to play with the shockwave filter...

```
var shock = new PIXI.filters.ShockwaveFilter();

image.filters = [shock]; 

stage.addChild(image);
```

Then in the raf function

```
shock.center.value = {x: cx, y: cx};
```

With cx being a dynamic value between 0 and 1. However nothing seems to change as the raf function is running. Am I doing something completely wrong?

None of the documentation for PIXI seems to make much sense to me, even looking at the source doesn't help.

Comment: Try removing the `.value` part. It should just be `shock.center = {x: cx, y: cx};`

Answer (score 3):

```
shock.center = {x: cx, y: cx};
```

And you need to **animate** the shockwave in you draw loop

```
shock.time = (shock.time >= 1 ) ? 0 : shock.time + 0.01;
```